# C# DataGridView AutoComplete goes to the next Row once the value is selected

Tags: c#, datagridview, autocomplete

I have a working autocomplete mode in my datagridview. The only problem is that when I select the value to fill the cell, the row switches to the one below.

I need the program to remain in the same row once the user selects the value given from the autocomplete. I show my code hopefully it can help.

```
private void entityLinesGrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        //this method helps to autocomplete the data in the field selected
        int column = entityLinesGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        string titleText = entityLinesGrid.Columns[column].HeaderText;//this line is getting the column name
        TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;

        if (autoText != null)
        {
            autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            //according to the column name the method will gather autocomplete data
            autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = dbConnect.dataFeeder(titleText);
            autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing in a sense that from the title… _”DataGridView AutoComplete goes to the next Row once the value is selected”_ … This is true that the default behavior of the grid is to go to the cell below when the user presses the “Enter” key. However this has nothing to do with the cells `AutoComplete` functionality. What you describe is changing the grids default behavior when the “Enter” key is pressed. So it may help if you [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking and any efforts on your part.

Comment: Hi JohnG. I already sort the problem of the enter key. It is actually as I am explaining. I have an autocomplete method which gives a box with suggestions, when i "CLICK" and not press enter, on a suggested value, then the row selected goes to the one underneath. Sorry but can't explain it better than that.

Comment: So I assume by your comment... _"I already sort the problem of the enter key."_ ... that you have solved this? If so, then great and good luck.